# Detect .gif with jquery

Tags: jquery, performance, dom

I have a page with a lot of images. I want to hide those images only if they are gif.

this is the structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="entry">
     <div class="image"><img src="imagefile.png" /> </div>
   </div>
  <div class="entry">
     <div class="image"><img src="imagefile.gif" /> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can filter All images this way:

```
$('.image').closest('.entry').not(".hidewrapper").wrap("<div class='hidewrapper' style=\"display:none\"></div>").closest('.entry').prepend("<a href=\"#\" class=\"unhideImage\" >show me</a>");
```

Because the site has a lot of images: Is there a way to filter only .gif - files WITHOUT a for-loop? Or am I just completely wrong that loops need much more performance than one-liners?

Comment: Something like `"img[src$=gif]"` or you can add some class to `img` with gifs when generating page, e.g. `<img class="isGif"` and use this class as a selector.

Comment: thanks. The second would not work, because I have no access to the sources but manipulate a foreign site (chrome extension)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can detect it with,

```
$('div.image img[src$=".gif"]')
```

Please read [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to know more about `attribute ends with selector`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**Attribute Ends With Selector [name$="value"]**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('.image img[src$=".gif"]')
```